App installation error: Missing 'shop' parameter error while creating shopify custom app with flask
trying to build shopify custom app to get product data  when installing app via distribution link its installing and redirect to Welcome .... Download Csv and i can download but the issue is when again going to app from shopify admin > apps its showing error on app dashboard "App installation error: Missing 'shop' parameter" trying many method but unable to again open welcome window and download csv below is my python script and using pythonanywhere for hosting
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, session, Response, url_for
import requests
import csv
import io
import logging
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'ece7312d5826c1cfc32ffbb2ff7ba4d21' #rabdom key 

# Shopify API credentials
API_KEY = "my app key here "
API_SECRET = "app secet key here "
APP_URL = "https://shopifyproductdata.pythonanywhere.com"

# Route for installing the app
@app.route('/')
def home():
    shop = request.args.get('shop')
    if shop:
        return redirect(f"https://{shop}/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={API_KEY}&scope=read_products&redirect_uri={APP_URL}/auth")
    return "App installation error: Missing 'shop' parameter", 400

@app.route('/auth')
def auth():
    shop = request.args.get('shop')
    code = request.args.get('code')

    # Ensure 'shop' and 'code' parameters are present
    if not shop or not code:
        return "App installation error: Missing 'shop' or 'code' parameter", 400

    # Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    access_token_url = f"https://{shop}/admin/oauth/access_token"
    payload = {
        "client_id": API_KEY,
        "client_secret": API_SECRET,
        "code": code
    }
    response = requests.post(access_token_url, json=payload)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
        session['shop'] = shop  # Set the 'shop' in the session here
        session['access_token'] = access_token
        return redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        logging.error(f"Error getting access token: {response.text}")
        return "Error getting access token", 400

# Dashboard route after authentication
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    shop = session.get('shop')

    if not shop:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))  # Redirect to home to reinitiate OAuth flow

    # Provide a link to download the CSV file
    return f"""
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <p>You can now download your product data from {shop}.</p>
        <a href="/download_csv">Download CSV</a>
    """



@app.route('/download_csv', methods=['GET'])
def download_csv():
    shop = session.get('shop')
    access_token = session.get('access_token')

    if not shop or not access_token:
        logging.error("Missing shop or access token in session")
        return redirect('/')

    # Shopify API URL
    API_URL = f"https://{shop}/admin/api/2024-07"
    headers = {
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token": access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    url = f"{API_URL}/products.json?fields=title,variants"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        products = response.json().get('products', [])
        csv_data = []

        # Prepare CSV data
        for product in products:
            for variant in product['variants']:
                row = {
                    "Title": product['title'],
                    "Price": variant['price'],
                    "Compare Price": variant.get('compare_at_price', 'N/A'),
                    "SKU": variant.get('sku', 'N/A'),
                    "Barcode": variant.get('barcode', 'N/A'),
                    "Inventory": variant.get('inventory_quantity', 'N/A')
                }
                csv_data.append(row)

        # Generate CSV response
        def generate():
            output = io.StringIO()
            writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=csv_data[0].keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in csv_data:
                writer.writerow(row)
            output.seek(0)  # Go to the start of the StringIO object before returning it
            return output.getvalue()

        return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv',
                        headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=product_report.csv"})

    logging.error(f"Failed to generate CSV. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    return "Failed to generate CSV", 500``` 

